# Submitting jobs to different fair scheduler pools while using jar option

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am relatively new to Hadoop and was trying to have different jobs of the same user submitted to different pools of the fair scheduler at run time while using the hadoop jar option.

Based on the solution in http://osdir.com/ml/hive-user-hadoop-apache/2009-03/msg00162.html, I used the `-D` option while running the job.

Specifically, I ran the command: `bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+' -D pool.name=sample_pool`

I can see the pool in the job tracker scheduler page, but the job is still submitted to user pool. I found that the `-D` option is not supported by the jar option: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/commands_manual.html#job.

How can I specify this at run time?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions:

- Have you restarted the job tracker since you made the changes suggested in the first link?
- You've previously needed to set all -D properties before the other arguments (i'm not sure if this has changed in more recent versions). Try:

  `bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar -Dpool.name=sample_pool grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'`

If probably doesn't matter, but i always bunch up the `-Dkey=value options` (no space between the `-D` and the `key=value`), i find it makes it more obvious that this is not part of the variable args list.

One way to verify this has been picked up correctly is to check the job's job.xml in the job tracker - does it have the pool.name property listed, and does it have the value you configured.

**EDIT** Just reading up on how the examples are bundles, you'll need to add the -D after the program name and before the other arguments:

```
`bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar grep -Dpool.name=sample_pool input output 'dfs[a-z.]+' `
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can specified the parameter `mapred.fairscheduler.pool` or `mapred.fairscheduler.poolnameproperty`.

For instance, you can run command

`bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar -Dmapred.fairscheduler.pool=sample_pool grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'`

**mapred.fairscheduler.pool:**

> Specify the pool that a job belongs in. If this is specified then mapred.fairscheduler.poolnameproperty is ignored.

**mapred.fairscheduler.poolnameproperty:**

> Specify which jobconf property is used to determine the pool that a job belongs in. String, default: user.name (i.e. one pool for each user). Another useful value is mapred.job.queue.name to use MapReduce's "queue" system for access control lists (see below). mapred.fairscheduler.poolnameproperty is used only for jobs in which mapred.fairscheduler.pool is not explicitly set.

**references**: 
[hadoop fair scheduler](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/fair_scheduler.html)